# Problems with date logstash

Tags: date, csv, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have a log in a CSV file with the date field in this pattern "24/09/2014", but when I read the file with Logstash the date field has a string type.

```
csv file example:
fecha,cant,canb,id,zon
24/09/2014,80,20,1.5,2
01/12/2014,50,25,1,3
```

My Logstash conf file:

```
input {  
  file {
    path => "path/to/data.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"    
  }
}
filter {  
  csv {
      separator => ","
      columns => ["fecha","cant","canb","id","zon"]
  }
date {
match=> ["fecha","dd/MM/yyyy"]
}
  mutate {convert => ["cant", "integer"]}
  mutate {convert => ["canb", "integer"]}
  mutate {convert => ["id", "float"]}
}
output {  
    elasticsearch {
        action => "index"
        host => "localhost"
        index => "barrena"
        workers => 1
    }
    stdout {}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: @Val thanks for the editing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date would be copied to a field called @timestamp ( The date filter does it ) and this field would be date format. 
You can safely remove the fetcha field once you have used the date filter.